# Accessing an Ember.Mixin within a custom handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there an elegant way of using methods defined in an Ember.Mixin object within a custom handlebars helper?

For example, in my case I have a mixin, `App.Format` which contains a bunch of different methods for formatting numbers, dates, ect and I would like to make some of these methods accessible directly from templates via custom helpers (e.g. `{{formatNumber 450324}}`). The reason I don't just put the method implementation directly in the helper instead of the mixin is that I also need these methods to be available in controllers, views, ect. And in the interest of keeping my code DRY, I definitely do not want to have duplicate code in the mixin and the helpers.

Is there any canonical, "emberish" way to accomplish this, or am I just thinking about it in the completely wrong way altogether?

**Edit:** Here is a jsbin to better illustrate the problem:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wunug/1/edit?html,js,output (look at lines 33-37)

Comment: I would create a helper which uses your mixin. Doc is available at http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/

Comment: @ppcano right, that's what I'm trying to access my mixin from, custom helpers that I've created with `Ember.Handlebars.helper()`. What I am having trouble with is how exactly I should be accessing/instantiating the mixin from within the helper function so that I can use its methods.

Comment: Is App.Format not available in your helper module? In that case, it's a problem with your module loader structure, otherwise write an example (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/) to help you better.

Comment: @ppcano I've added a jsbin to better show what I mean. The object `App.Format` itself is defined and available with the helper function,  I just don't know how to access its methods, i.e. I can't just create an instance of it via `var format = new App.Format()` or `var format = App.Format.create()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [Mixin.apply](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html#method_apply) makes the job.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('formatNumber', function(num, decimals) {
  var format = App.Format.apply({});
  return format.formatNumber(num, decimals || 2);
});
```

Comment: ahh, perfect! I actually did glance over the apply() method when I was hunting through the api docs, but I guess its lack of description caused me to overlook it. :)

Comment: Question: wouldn't this instantiate the Mixin each time the helper is called?  That usually wouldn't be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ember 2.12 and this is what I worked for me. Hopefully this helps somebody.

Create a new mixin named formatter:

../mixins/formatters.js

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Mixin.create({
        shortDate: function(date) {
            return `Date should be formatted: ${date}`;
        }
    });
```

Create a new helper that imports the above mixin and uses it.

../helpers/short-date.js

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    import FormatDateMixin from '../mixins/formatters';

    export default Ember.Helper.extend(FormatDateMixin,  {
      compute: function(params /*, hash*/) {
        return this.shortDate(params);
      }
    });
```

In the template *.hbs file, use the helper as below:

```
    {{short-date today}}
```